# React Mapping over an array of objects and displaying the user whos ID matches objects foreignkey

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, orm

I'm new at posting/coding so forgive me if I miss on anything, I have two arrays filled with objects being grabbed by useSelector, 1 array for posts, the other are the users info whom has a foreignkey in the posts object.  I'm mapping over "allUsers" which is an array of objects that hold each users info.  I want to key into each objects foreignkey and render the users info whos id matches that FK of the post im mapping over, it works until I refresh and am hit with the error "cannot read property of undefined". I can get the users info in each object by keying into each user object by chaining the posts foreign key. `posts.map(post => allUsers[post.user_id].username.`  > even trying to key into the objects by index like `allUsers[2].username` is still showing a typeError: cannot read property username of undefined  Sorry If I made it a bit confusing!

```
enter coduseEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPosts())
}, [dispatch])

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllUsers())
}, [dispatch])


const show = (post) => {
    setPostsId(post.id);
    setClicked(!clicked)
}
console.log(posts)
// console.log("allUsers Object", allUsers[user.id].username)


return (
    <>
        <div className='home-container'>
            <ul className='post-list'>
                {posts.slice(0).reverse().map((post, idx) => {

                    return (
                        <li key={idx} className="indv-post">


                            <div className="post-header">
                                <strong className="homepage-username">{allUsers[post.user_id].username}</strong>

                                {post.user_id === user.id &&
                                    <button className='post-dropdown' onClick={() => show(post)}><BiDotsHorizontalRounded /></button>

                                }
```

> This is the arrays structure for both users and posts, each have multiple objects

```
post: [{caption: "example caption", comments_count: 0, id: 1, likes_count: 0, picture_url: "https://PICTUREURL.jpg", …}]

user: [{biography: "A BIOGRAPHY", email: "demo@aa.io", id: 4, profile_picture: "https://PROFILEPICTURE.png", username: "demo", user_id: 4 }]



const { id } = useParams()
const post = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
// const user = useSelector(state => state.session.user);
// const allUsers = useSelector(state => Object.values(state.users))
// const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
// const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = useState(false);
// const [showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal] = useState(false);
// const [postsId, setPostsId] = useState(0);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [ postObj, setPostObj ] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (post) {
         const newPost = post[id];
         console.log('post object', newPost);

         setPostObj(newPost);
      }
   }, [post, id]);
```

this little useEffect did the trick, thank you everybody

Comment: What does `allUsers` look like?

Comment: Check whether `allUsers` array contains at least 3 objects of `user`. Otherwise it will return an uncaught error if you're trying to get `username` from an `undefined` object.

Comment: the allUsers is the user array at the bottom, it has more than 3 objs

Comment: Is it possible to add a codesandbox link with your code?